# Flex 3 or Flash Builder 4 for development of Church management system

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, flash, builder

i am a learner of flex 3 builder and i have downloaded the Flash Builder beta 2. i have been experimenting with it for a while, i have been given the task to develop a church management system for my church.

Because i am new to both technologies, i wanted advice actually as to which will be fastest to build such an application. The application is going to pull data from a MySql database, so its generally going to be a CRUD interface with some charts and ability to generate reports as well. 
Will be very grateful for an immediate answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Best solution: don't use Flash at all.

Comment: from the mouths of babes

Comment: remember either way your going to need some "middleware" Flex/Flash can't communicate directly with a database (well AIR can but you didn't mention if you were using it or not). So you're going to need some coldFusion or php or something to bridge that gap.

Answer (score 2):

Go with Flash builder, since it's just the newer version of Flex builder and much easier to use.
That is, of course, if you want to make it in Flash/Flex/AIR. There are other options as well.

Comment: If this answer is correct, you should accept it (the check icon) ;)

Answer (score 2):

As one of the commentors noted, you can't talk directly from Flex/Flash to a MySQL database. If you're building a CMS you might want to start with something like Drupal. Drupal has a fairly easy way to integrate Flash/Flex via the Drupal Services module - http://devzone.zend.com/article/2660

That should make it easy to add some interactive charts or a dashboard built in Flex while Drupal will do the work of talking to a database and managing content.

As for the original question, I'd use Flash Builder 4. It's released as of today - http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/ - and includes functionality like a network monitor and wizards to get you up and running with PHP and Flex.

=Ryan

ryan@adobe.com

Comment: thank you very much ryan, actually it is not just any cms, i need to build an application actually that will manage people's information in my church. will welcome any help with that, will send u an email.